# CiviCase Timelines based on specific values of fields

Tags: civicase, civirules, activity

I’m new here, so sorry if I’m asking something too obvious, but I couldn’t find an answer in Civi manual to it. The manual stats that “…if one of the activities in your standard timeline is a medical evaluation, you could have 2 or more timelines that outline different schedules of medical treatment and add one of these to the case depending on the outcome of the original medical evaluation.” However, I couldn’t find anywhere how to I set a timeline which is dependent on another field value. Thanks

Edit: Could I do it with CiviRules, maybe? Or any other better option?

Edit 2: Yes, was able to do it with CiviRules

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe unclear but when it says "and add one of these to the case depending on the outcome of the original medical evaluation" it means the case manager would manually add the appropriate timeline after assessing the situation. Not based on the value of a field but on a variety of factors requiring professional evaulation.